# Selecting a group within a in R

Tags: r

Hello I was wondering how to select a group within a group and plot the results.

For example I have a group called "type" and within the type I have:

photo, video, text

I want to take out only photo and plot the likes the photo got. I hope this made sense. I need it in R. I know in python i would use pandas.

Comment: With `library(tidyverse)` you can filter to a single category with `filter()`. For example `data %>% filter(type == "photo")`

Comment: A working example: `library(tidyverse); iris %>% filter(Species == "setosa")`

Comment: A group of what? Are you trying to subset a data frame? Take a look again at [ask] and see how to make a [mcve], but questions on subsetting data (if that's what you're trying to do) have been covered pretty extensively on SO already, so you should be able to search around the r tag and find something

Comment: Lots of ways to do this. Try `help(Extract)`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.